# how to fix "stale data access" in memcached

Tags: java, caching, memcached, distributed

We are facing an issue with memcached (v1.4.4 on Redhat) that is accurately described below:

*With consistent ketama hashing in memcached, there is no strict state for where a given key lives. In the absence of up-to-date key-server remapping info, clients might read or write a key from a wrong memcached server and that will lead to either stale or inconsistent data. For example, if there is any network disruption, and one or more clients decide that a particular memcached server is not available anymore, they will automatically rehash some data into the rest of the nodes even if the original one is still available. If the node eventually returns to service (for example after the network outage is resolved), the data on that node will be out of date and the clients without updated keyserver remapping info will read stale data.*

Is there a way to solve this without going for an expensive commercial software alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have troubles with your implementation, I gave some input to a similar question here: [How to handle recovery memcached nodes when using spymemcached & HashAlgorithm.KETAMA_HASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975889/how-to-handle-recovery-memcached-nodes-when-using-spymemcached-hashalgorithm-k/) Hopefully it will help you too.